# Github Actions MSBuild Static Library LINK : fatal error LNK1561: entry point must be defined

Tags: c++, visual-studio, msbuild, github-actions, vcxproj

I made a C++ project in Visual Studio. Initially I was getting `LINK : fatal error LNK1561: entry point must be defined` when trying to build, but I fixed that by changing the Configuration Type in Project Properties to Static Library (.lib)

Now I created a Github Actions workflow to automatically build this project and it still gives the above error even though the .vcxproj contains `<ConfigurationType>StaticLibrary</ConfigurationType>`.

Why is it still giving this error when the project is configured as a static library?

Github Actions yml:

```
...
env:
  # Path to the solution file relative to the root of the project.
  SOLUTION_FILE_PATH: .

  # Configuration type to build.
  BUILD_CONFIGURATION: Release

permissions:
  contents: read

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: Add MSBuild to PATH
      uses: microsoft/setup-msbuild@v1.0.2

    - name: Build
      working-directory: ${{env.GITHUB_WORKSPACE}}
      # Add additional options to the MSBuild command line here (like platform or verbosity level).
      # See https://docs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference
      run: msbuild /m /p:Configuration=${{env.BUILD_CONFIGURATION}} ${{env.SOLUTION_FILE_PATH}}
```

Comment: You will have to show us your `.vcxproj` file. If you added `ConfigurationType` to the wrong place, this error definitely can remain because your GitHub Actions produces Release build, not Debug build (which is the usual default in VS).

Comment: Ah, that's it! I only set ConfigurationType for Debug build, but not Release.